# ASP.Net Formview skipping records when paging

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, formview

I have a formview that binds to an Entity Framework datasource using the following code:

```
Private Sub LoadFormviewData()
    Dim ctx As New SNOTEntities
    Dim RepCalls = ctx.SNOT_RepCall_view
    Dim strSQL As New StringBuilder
    strSQL.Append("select * from SNOT_RepCall_view where DateInput >= '")
    strSQL.Append(Startdate.ToShortDateString)
    strSQL.Append("' and DateInput <= '")
    strSQL.Append(EndDate.ToShortDateString)
    If IncReviewed = "N" Then
        strSQL.Append("' and Reviewed = 'N'")
    Else
        strSQL.Append("'")
    End If
    strSQL.Append(" order by IssueID")

    Dim calls = RepCalls.SqlQuery(strSQL.ToString)
    FormView1.DataSource = calls.ToList
    FormView1.DataBind()
    If 1 = 1 Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Using the AllowPaging=true I find that it skips every other record when paging. I am new to EF and not that good at ASP.net so forgive me if you require any more info.

I use the IndexChanging and Indexchanged events to save/populate fields that are outside of the formview (too much code to post unless requested)

I have confirmed that the correct amount of records are in 'calls' and that they make it into the Formview datasource. It just skips every other record when paging. Have stared at this code for days. Any help/suggestions welcome.

Formview markup:

```
         <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" Height="521px" Width="375px" HorizontalAlign="Left" AllowPaging="True">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:label ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("IssueID")%>'/>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="<%# FormView1.PageIndex%>"></asp:Label>
            <table border="1" style="width: 375px; ">
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="LabelBold" Text="Call Date:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCallDate" runat="server" CssClass="LabelNormal" Text='<%#Eval("CallDate", "{0:dd/M/yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" CssClass="LabelBold" Text='Input Date:'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblInputDate" runat="server" CssClass="LabelNormal" Text='<%#Eval("DateInput", "{0:dd/M/yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" CssClass="LabelBold" Text='<%#Eval("IssueTypeName")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStore" runat="server" CssClass="LabelBold" Text='<%#Eval("StoreName")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" CssClass="LabelBold" Text="Rep:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRep" runat="server" CssClass="LabelNormal" Text='<%#Eval("InputByName")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCust" runat="server" CssClass="LabelBold" Text='<%#Eval("CustName")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="LabelBold" Text="Vendor:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblVendor" runat="server" CssClass="LabelNormal" Text='<%#Eval("Vendor")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="LabelBold" Text="Rep Notes:"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDetails" runat="server" CssClass="LabelNormal" Text='<%#Eval("Details")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="LabelBold" Text="Reviewer Notes:"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRevNotes" runat="server" Height="130px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="345px" Text='<%#Eval("ReviewerNotes")%>' ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </ItemTemplate> 
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                There is nothing to see here.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" Mode="NumericFirstLast" />

<%--            <PagerTemplate>
                <table style="border: thin solid #000000; width: 375px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 80px" >
                           <%-- <asp:linkButton
            id="lnkPrevious"
            Text="Prev"
            CommandName="Page"
            CommandArgument="Prev"
            Runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td  style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center; width: 215px">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="<%#    FormView1.PageCount - FormView1.PageIndex -1%>"></asp:Label>
                            &nbsp;more to go
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 80px">
                            <asp:linkButton
            id="lnkNext"
            Text="Next"
            CommandName="Page"
            CommandArgument="Next"
            Runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </PagerTemplate>--%>

    </asp:FormView>
```

The pagertemplate is commented out as part of my testing leaving just the default version.

Comment: The markup for the formview would be useful. You have any rowdatabound events?

Comment: Here is the aspx code for the formview. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I don't see any issues there. Maybe something in the indexing events. I usually debug the ItemDataBound event for something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will take a look at it. My hunch is something somewhere is firing twice when the next record is requested. I do a lot in the databound, indexchanging and indexchanged events but am darned if I can find out what is wrong. Interesting thing is that the formview pageindex is correct but it jumps over a record in the data. Abandoning the formview in the morning if I get nowhere tonight.